# What do the word "classy" and the word "smart - assy" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

> First and foremost, I am a mother to a beautiful soul, who is my entire universe. If children aren't your thing, please don't waste your time reading any further. I want to end up with someone who sees her as the best part of me, because that is exactly what she is. FYI: her father and I maintain a brilliant co-parenting relationship.
>
> I am loyal, intelligent, spontaneous, sassy,**classy** and a bit **smart-assy** . I love to travel, and most of the time I have my trips planned out 6-12 months in advance. But I can also be persuaded to fly by the seat of my pants and pack up to go on a whim.
>
> I am gainfully employed and enjoy what I do quite a bit. Not much work-related traveling these days, however,  I'm known to pull a few late-nighters occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

Smart-assy is a nonstandard adjective form of '[Smart ass](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/smart+ass)'.

[Classy is in the dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/classy), so I'll just leave that one alone.

Comment: The author thought they were being clever by making the sentence rhyme, and in doing so corrupted the formal use of the word.

Comment: I like the way you think, Sir. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of something I heard on the radio from a show which originated in the midwest section of the USA. The announcer referred to some political group as **right-wingy**.

The **-y** suffix appended to a noun converts the noun into an adjective that means  to be like the thing referred to by that noun, or having many, though perhaps not all, of the qualities thereof.

Sass becomes sass*y*, class becomes class*y*, and smart-ass becomes smart-ass*y*.

It is very productive in English, especially informally, because native speakers will append it to almost anything.

Comment: This reminds me of an [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/1443/).